# Not able to get all songs from a device on Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to learn how to develop an Android app and I found a very useful tutorial on the web which was trying to create a simple music player.

Even though I followed it, I've got a problem:
When I try to run the app, I don't get any error in the compiler, but on the emulator the app won't start with the following error message:

> Unfortunately, MusicPlayer has stopped.

This is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ArrayList<Song> songList;
private ListView songView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    songView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.song_list);
    songList = new ArrayList<Song>();
    getSongList();
}

public void getSongList(){
    // retrieve song info
    ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);
    if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
        //get columns

        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        //add songs to list
        do {
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
            songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));
        }
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

}

After reviewing the code a bit, I found out that the app crashes when I call the following command:

```
Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);
```

Any idea of what's the problem?

Comment: Maybe the external storage isn't present on the emulator. Also, do you have put some musics to find into the emulator?

Comment: @gymnif I thought the problem was related to not providing any columns to select in the `query()` function, though I am basing that purely off the documentation, and I am not familiar with Android.  Are all those `null` variables ok for the query statement?

Comment: I've never used that way for my projects. I've used a recursive function to scan the memory of the device and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html

You need to pass in more arguments than you are.  The second parameter should be a string array of column names, and it seems that without that you won't be able to select any data.

Snippet from the documentation:

```
// Queries the user dictionary and returns results
mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
    UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI,   // The content URI of the words table
    mProjection,                        // The columns to return for each row
    mSelectionClause                    // Selection criteria
    mSelectionArgs,                     // Selection criteria
    mSortOrder);                        // The sort order for the returned rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you granted permission to read external storage?